# handleActionWithIdentifier : forRemoteNotification not called WatchKit

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, watchkit, apple-watch

I have a notification that does not have any actions- just the default dismiss action that comes with all notifications. What method is called for the watch when a notification is tapped in the watch notification center? Not an action, but just the body of the notification.

I am looking at the Apple documentation and I'm assuming it is handleActionWithIdentifier : forRemoteNotification, but wherever I put this, it is not getting called when I tap on a notification from the notification center.
[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840263/watchkit-handleactionwithidentifier-forremotenotification-is-not-called) is similar, but no answers have been found that help me.

Am I correct in thinking that handleActionWithIdentifier will still work if no action was selected? According to the documentation: "If the identifier parameter contains an empty string, that means the user launched your WatchKit app from the notification interface without choosing a specific action."

Is my problem that handleActionWithIdentifier isn't called because I'm not handling an action? Or should I be using a different method?

All I need to be able to do is access the notification payload if my watch app is opened from a notification that has been sitting in the notification center. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.